# Migrating legacy TFS extension from TFS 2015 to TFS 2017: WITCONTROLS.WorkItemControl gone?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

Background: We have some legacy TFS extensions running in TFS 2015 update 1. We're migrating those extensions to TFS 2017.

Problem: We have the following line in one of our extensions:

`ExtensionName.inherit(WITCONTROLS.WorkItemControl, { ...`

`WorkItemControl` no longer seems to exist in TFS 2017. Anyone know the new API endpoint to call?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's the top of the extension:

```
TFS.module("ExtensionProject.ExtensionName",
[
    "TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls",
    "TFS.WorkItemTracking"
],
function () {
    // module content
    var tfsContext = require("Presentation/Scripts/TFS/TFS.Host.TfsContext");
    var vssCore = require("VSS/Utils/Core");
    var WITOM = TFS.WorkItemTracking,
        WITCONTROLS = TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls,
        TFSHost = tfsContext.TfsContext,
        delegate = vssCore.delegate,
        moduleBaseUrl = TFS.getModuleBase("ExtensionProject.ExtensionName.js");
```

Comment: You get the issue when you upload this legacy extension to TFS 2017? Is there any error message? Did you enable this legacy extension after uploading?

Comment: @Tingting0929-MSFT Yes, legacy extension is installed and enabled. I'm not getting an error message in browser debugger. I'm just trying to figure out what call has replaced `WITCONTROLS.WorkItemControl`.

Answer (score 1):

TFS.WorkItemTracking.Controls no longer consists WorkItemControl class. use WorkItemTracking/Scripts/Controls/WorkItemForm/WorkItemControl.